# todonotes get cut off in margin of twoside document

Tags: todonotes

I am using the following `twoside` document layout and the `todonotes` package. My problem is the `\todo{...}` notes get cut off in the margin. How can I fix this?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\todo{Why don't I fit on the page?}

\end{document}
```

**Edited**

Interestingly, when I remove `twoside` the notes do fit?

[image]

**In response to some proposed solutions**

- I can't change my page margins.
- If I use `textwidth=14mm`, I get a weird output on the second page of my `twoside` document. See for example this MWE:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[textwidth=14mm]{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{I fit on the page}
\newpage
\blindtext\todo{Why don't I fit on the page?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your todonotes are currently too wide to fit into a margin of 2 cm width. To resolve this, you have several options:

1: Increase the margin size:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=35mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{Why don't I fit on the page?}
\end{document}
```

2: Use the `textwidth` package option to globally decrease the width of the `todonotes` to a value that fits into the margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[textwidth=20mm]{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{Why don't I fit on the page?}
\end{document}
```

3: Reset the `\marginparwidth` as described in section '1.6.6 Todonotes wrongly placed in the margin' of the `todonotes` manual:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{Why don't I fit on the page?}
\end{document}
```

4: Add the `marginparwidth` as an option to `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm,marginparwidth=35pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\the\marginparwidth
\blindtext\todo{Why don't I fit on the page?}
\end{document}
```

---

You can of course adjust the values in version 2,3 and 4 according to your needs. To achieve a result that is as similar as possible to the output without the `twoside` option, you could use version 3 as follows: `\setlength{\marginparwidth}{35pt}` 35pt is the marginparwidth that is used in an article document without the `twoside` option. You can find this out with the following MWE, that will just print the value of the current marginparwidth into the pdf.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=40mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\the\marginparwidth
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Milo: I can confirm that option 2 does lead to the output you showed in your question. However, version 3 and 4 work for me as expected.