# Todonote, problem withe the position of the messagebox

Tags: todonotes

[image]

Might anyone know what the problem is as to why I am getting the note-box outside the page border?

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside=true]{scrreprt}
%\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{TUWBIDA}
%% this style includes already some packages which have been very useful 
%% in the last diploma or doctoral theses


\raggedbottom 
%% prevents the expansion of the text till the end of the page (if you like)
%\setcapindent{0em} %% influences captions layout

%% use biblatex and biber for bibliography
%% customize options as you like
%% style=numeric-comp ... [1]
%% style=authoryear ... Mang 1998 / use \textcite{} ... Mang (1998)
%%
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  giveninits=true,maxbibnames=99}%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\;al\adddot},
urlseen = {Zugriff am}}
\addbibresource{Literatur-Citavi.bib}


%% ===== additional packages to the ones already loaded ==============
\usepackage{color}
%new
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}%to put the Figre in the position when use [H]
\usepackage{subcaption} %subcaption in subfigure 
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\def\inch#1{#1''}
\def\ft#1{#1'\thinspace}
%\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,textwidth=3cm]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\todoINFO}[1]{\todo[color=blue!25]{INFO: #1}}
\newcommand{\todoIMPORTANT}[1]{\todo[color=red!25]{IMPORTANT: #1}}
\newcommand{\todoREV}[1]{\todo[color=green!25]{REVIEWED: #1}}
%%% end of the new cods
%%==============
\usepackage{acro}
%\acsetup{only-used=false,extra-style=plain,list-heading = chapter*}

%new for acronyms
\newlength\myitemwidth
\setlength\myitemwidth{90pt}
\newlist{listabbrev}{description}{1}
\setlist[listabbrev]{
    labelindent = 0pt,
    labelsep    = 0pt,
    itemsep     = -2pt plus .2pt,
    leftmargin  = \myitemwidth,
    labelwidth  = \myitemwidth,
    format      = \normalfont
}

\DeclareAcroListStyle{styleabbrev}{list}{list = listabbrev}

\acsetup{list-style   = styleabbrev,
    %list-heading = chapter*,
    list-name    = Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
    only-used=false
}


%end for acronyms

\input{Acronyms}

%% ===== additional settings =============
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,},
range-phrase = --,
group-separator = {~},
per-mode = symbol, 
list-final-separator={ und }}

\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}

%% examples for useful shortcuts in German
\newcommand{\zB}{\mbox{z.\,B.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Name}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\idR}{\mbox{i.\,d.\,R.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\IdR}{\mbox{I.\,d.\,R.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ua}{\mbox{u.\,a.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\lt}{\mbox{lt.\,}\xspace}
\newcommand{\bzw}{\mbox{bzw.\,}\xspace}
\newcommand{\vgl}{\mbox{vgl.\,}\xspace}
\newcommand{\vKTxv}{\mathbf{v}_1^T\tilde{\mathbf{K}}_{T},_{\xi}\mathbf{v}_1}
\newcommand{\vKTxxv}{\mathbf{v}_1^T\tilde{\mathbf{K}}_{T},_{\xi\xi}\mathbf{v}_1}


% activate for double space between the lines (correction mode) 
%\doublespacing

\begin{document}       %% start of the document
\maketitle             %% places the title with above information
\listoftodos
\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{ngerman}  %% for german abstract
\include{00-Kurzfassung}      %% german abstract (about 1 page)

\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{english}    %% for english abstract
\include{00-abstract}         %% english abstract (about 1 page)

%\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{ngerman} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\printacronyms[name=Formelzeichen,include-classes=Formelzeichen ]
\printacronyms[name=Abkürzungen,include-classes=Abkurz]
%\printacronyms[name=Abkürzungen,include-classes=Kleine griechische Buchstaben]
%\printacronyms[name=Einheiten]
%\printacronyms
%\acuse{Formel}
%\acuse{Abkuerzung}

%\acuseall
%% now include all chapter files -- use the include-command (takes care
%% that all not yet output floats are output before the new file)
%%
\include{01-Einleitung}
\include{02-Grundlagen}
\include{03-Tragverhalten}
\include{0_NumerischeSimualtiondocument}
\include{04-Experimentelle Untersuchung}
\include{05-Auswertung}
\include{06-Ergebnisse}

%\include{}
%etc.

%% insert bibliography, adds chapter heading with chapter number
\printbibliography




\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Give the code that produces this error so that everyone can review and correct it.

Comment: It's better, but it is not the complete code. It has to start with `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AndréC  hier is the code ! thank you very much for ur help!

Comment: @Hussein, it is easier for us to fix problems when your code is minimal, having only the little that is required to recreate the problem. Also, your code does not compile because of missing fies. That said, I think this would help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435715/90297

Comment: Where did you find the package `\usepackage{TUWBIDA}` ?  Please give a Minimum Working Example (MWE) as explained here: [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: @EladDen very helpful ! thanks !